# Can't set property of Javascript object

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

I'm trying to set properties of a Javascript object (I'm speculating that it's not a plain JS Object but an instance of some kind of class, but I can't find what the class is)

[image]

This is what the object looks like when I log it.

```
result.data.info = {};

console.log(result.data);

result.data.info.UUID = uuid;

result.data.info.totalStressValue = totalValue;

console.log(result.data);
```

This blows up because result.data.info is undefined. I'm pretty sure it's a Jquery object, how can I set these properties? Thanks.

Comment: can you try using `JSON.Stringify()` on console

Comment: either you didn't provide the complete code, or you should first do result.data = {}, then result.data.info = {}

Comment: You have a few `console.log` statements there. What are their outputs?

Answer (score 0):

you can initialize the whole object like this:

```
result = {
    data: {
        info: {
            UUID: uuid,
            totalStressValue: totalValue
        }
    }
}
```